# How to override CSS Box Sizing for just one area on page?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following CSS inside my Twitter Bootstrap file:

```
*,
*:before,
*:after {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

It is causing a problem with my TinyMCE editor, mainly the resizing of the textarea. Anyway if I remove the above code all is good, but obviously I need it in place cause otherwise the rest of Bootstrap breaks.

So how do I override the above for just TinyMCE? I tried this:

```
.tinymce-editor,
.tinymce-editor:before,
.tinymce-editor:after {
    -webkit-box-sizing: content-box !important;
    -moz-box-sizing: content-box !important;
    box-sizing: content-box !important;
}
```

But no luck. `.tinymce-editor` happens to be the div that my editor is inside.

Comment: I was just going to suggest `.tinymce-editor *`.. you probably don't need `!important` though.

Comment: Try avoiding using `!important` by adding another level of selector, aka `.parent .tinymce-editor *,`

Comment: @TK123 You can answer your own question. Instead of adding the answer to the question add it as an answer.

Comment: As @hitautodestruct said, you need to post the answer as an answer, not an edit.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Nevermind just got it:

```
.tinymce-editor *,
.tinymce-editor *:before,
.tinymce-editor *:after {
    -webkit-box-sizing: content-box !important;
    -moz-box-sizing: content-box !important;
    box-sizing: content-box !important;
}
```

Comment: Just an FYI that the `*` selector has a harsh effect on performance  when there are many DOM elements on the page, or in you're case under the `.tinymce-editor` class.

Comment: Actually leave out the *. I wasn't able to make this work with the * left in. My problem was bootstrap stepping on datatables.net.

Comment: * did the worked, I added just the class name, but it was not working, .calss name and * did it.. thanks buddy.