# How can I remove box-sizing: border-box from Bootstrap CSS?

Tags: css, sharepoint, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am building a SharePoint 2013 site and I'm including Bootstrap minified css v3.3.4 files within the site to be able to use their tabs for organizational purposes.

This thing is the inclusion of the Bootstrap CSS makes it so that the "Help" symbol and the "Focus on Content" button get slightly messed up. The problem is one line of code within this bootstrap CSS file. It is "box-sizing:border-box;" and when it is turned off (while using the Inspect Element tool) everything looks just fine again. What I'm asking is how can I remove/turn off this line of code within the CSS file so I can include this CSS file with no issues?

**Note:** I'm asking this here because it has to do with CSS and Bootstrap - asking it on the SharePoint stack exchange doesn't really fit the question.

Thanks.

Comment: If you want to remove it completely, just edit the css file...and remove it.

Comment: The problem is where should I remove it from? When I search through the text file there are twelve places where that line is used. Should I delete every reference to it? Or is there a specific one of those twelve that I should get rid of?

Comment: Frankly, I'm not that familiar with the intracies of Bootstrap but if you've identified the places where it is just comment each one out until you get the results you want.

Comment: I just opened the CSS and deleted all references to that line of formatting and that did the trick. It introduces a new error with SharePoint but exclusively within Chrome. I, the creator, am actually the only person to use Chrome with the site so this is fine for now. I'll work on a fix for that.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem with my SharePoint 2013 sites as well when using bootstrap in my branding. You will need to override the effects by adding another css file AFTER the corev15.css and the bootstrap.css references, with the following:

```
#suiteBar *, #s4-ribbonrow * 
{
    -webkit-box-sizing: initial;
    -moz-box-sizing: initial;
    box-sizing:content-box;
}
```

This will target box-sizing:content-box to just the suiteBar and ribbon rows sections of the SharePoint page. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

I know I am late to this post, but I just experience this issue.
When I inserted my custom HTML into my SharePoint 2013 page (using a CEWP) it messed up the exact same symbols in the suite bar.

To fix it I had to go into the bootstrap.min.css and change `box-sizing:border-box` to `box-sizing:content-box`.

The line of code in the bootstrap.min.css to change is below:

*{-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;-moz-box-sizing:border-box;`box-sizing:content-box`}:after,:before{-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;-moz-box-sizing:border-box;box-sizing:border-box}

But then my custom table headers and wells extended out past the container area. To fix that, I found the answer here [How to override CSS Box Sizing for just one area on page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20430050/how-to-override-css-box-sizing-for-just-one-area-on-page)

The inline CSS I used to get my web part to correct itself is:

```
.container *,
.container *:before,
.container *:after {
    -webkit-box-sizing: content-box !important;
    -moz-box-sizing: content-box !important;
    box-sizing: border-box !important;
}
```

Keep in mind...I am only using bootstrap for a specific web part. I do not need bootstrap for my entire site. Not to mention, I am very much a novice. I'm pretty descent at manipulating others code to get what I need, but I am still honing my skills at good practices...I say that because someone may have a comment on how I fixed this issue.

Answer (score 1):

There may be issues with doctype and quirks mode.

- make sure you have a `<!DOCTYPE html>` at the top of your pages
- try to include a type attribute on your style tag (shouldn't be needed with HTML5) and make sure the style override is included below the bootstrap import
- add !important to the style override

  `<style type="text/css"> 
     #ms-help,  #fullscreenmodebox {box-sizing: content-box !important;}
  </style>`

Comment: Should I be adding those lines of code within the CSS file itself? Currently I have it so that the page will load the CSS files from where they are stored in a site library and after that is done the code for the style (as you have above) is supposed to activate but it still does nothing.

Comment: You could add `#ms-help,  #fullscreenmodebox {box-sizing: content-box !important;}` to the end of the css file.

Comment: I think functionally that would do the same as what @MiguelGatmaytan said and it does in fact fix my symbol error - the CSS also just introduces a new one for a user in chrome. That's alright though. I just deleted the lines and it works the same as adding this code.